# Spring reactive WebClient proxy setting not working with standalone application - SpringBoot 2.5.11

Tags: proxy, spring-webflux, reactor-netty

#### The proxy setting works fine with simple CURL and RestTemplate but fails with WebClient, the application is a simple standalone app.

---

**Env details**

> JDK - 1.8.0_301

> Springboot - 2.5.11

---

**Sample Code**

```java
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.client.reactive.ReactorClientHttpConnector;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient;

import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;
import reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient;
import reactor.netty.transport.ProxyProvider;

public class Test {
  private static ReactorClientHttpConnector getConnection() {
        String proxyHost = "xxx.xxx.xxx";
        int proxyPort = 9506;
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create().wiretap(true)
                .proxy(proxy -> proxy.type(ProxyProvider.Proxy.HTTP).host(proxyHost).port(proxyPort)).noSSL();

        return new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient);
  }

  //main method
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String baseUrl = "http://www.someapi.com";
        String loginUrl = "/security/login.json";

        WebClient client = WebClient.builder().clientConnector(getConnection()).baseUrl(baseUrl).build();

        Mono<User> user = client.post().uri(loginUrl).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .cookie(C_XSRF_TOKEN, TOKEN_VALUE).headers(h -> h.add(XSRF_TOKEN, TOKEN_VALUE)).bodyValue(getAuthBean())
                .retrieve().bodyToMono(User.class);

        System.out.println("--------------------");
        System.out.println(user.block());
        System.out.println("--------------------");
  }
}
```

---

**Logs**

```
16:08:41.577 [main] DEBUG reactor.util.Loggers - Using Slf4j logging framework
16:08:41.606 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.logging.InternalLoggerFactory - Using SLF4J as the default logging framework
16:08:41.610 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - -Dio.netty.noUnsafe: false
16:08:41.610 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - Java version: 8
16:08:41.612 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - sun.misc.Unsafe.theUnsafe: available
16:08:41.616 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - sun.misc.Unsafe.copyMemory: available
16:08:41.617 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - java.nio.Buffer.address: available
16:08:41.617 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - direct buffer constructor: available
16:08:41.617 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - java.nio.Bits.unaligned: available, true
16:08:41.617 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.allocateUninitializedArray(int): unavailable prior to Java9
16:08:41.617 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.(long, int): available
16:08:41.617 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent - sun.misc.Unsafe: available
16:08:41.618 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent - -Dio.netty.tmpdir: /var/folders/r1/zvvh7_rj03jg3jp14n4yrtw907zgf0/T (java.io.tmpdir)
16:08:41.618 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent - -Dio.netty.bitMode: 64 (sun.arch.data.model)
16:08:41.618 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent - Platform: MacOS
16:08:41.619 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent - -Dio.netty.maxDirectMemory: 3817865216 bytes
16:08:41.619 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent - -Dio.netty.uninitializedArrayAllocationThreshold: -1
16:08:41.620 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.CleanerJava6 - java.nio.ByteBuffer.cleaner(): available
16:08:41.620 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent - -Dio.netty.noPreferDirect: false
16:08:41.709 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.ResourceLeakDetector - -Dio.netty.leakDetection.level: simple
16:08:41.710 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.ResourceLeakDetector - -Dio.netty.leakDetection.targetRecords: 4
--------------------
16:08:42.042 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.NetUtil - -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack: false
16:08:42.043 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.NetUtil - -Djava.net.preferIPv6Addresses: false
16:08:42.045 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.NetUtilInitializations - Loopback interface: lo0 (lo0, 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo0)
16:08:42.046 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.NetUtil - Failed to get SOMAXCONN from sysctl and file /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn. Default: 128
16:08:42.062 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunctions - [5ab956d7] HTTP POST http://xxxx/security/login.json
16:08:42.072 [main] DEBUG reactor.netty.tcp.TcpResources - [http] resources will use the default LoopResources: DefaultLoopResources {prefix=reactor-http, daemon=true, selectCount=8, workerCount=8}
16:08:42.072 [main] DEBUG reactor.netty.tcp.TcpResources - [http] resources will use the default ConnectionProvider: reactor.netty.resources.DefaultPooledConnectionProvider@7eecb5b8
16:08:42.199 [main] DEBUG reactor.netty.resources.PooledConnectionProvider - Creating a new [http] client pool [PoolFactory{evictionInterval=PT0S, leasingStrategy=fifo, maxConnections=500, maxIdleTime=-1, maxLifeTime=-1, metricsEnabled=false, pendingAcquireMaxCount=1000, pendingAcquireTimeout=45000}] for [xxxx:80]
16:08:42.216 [main] DEBUG reactor.netty.resources.DefaultLoopIOUring - Default io_uring support : false
16:08:42.233 [main] DEBUG reactor.netty.resources.DefaultLoopEpoll - Default Epoll support : false
16:08:42.234 [main] DEBUG reactor.netty.resources.DefaultLoopKQueue - Default KQueue support : false
16:08:42.241 [main] DEBUG io.netty.channel.MultithreadEventLoopGroup - -Dio.netty.eventLoopThreads: 16
16:08:42.260 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.InternalThreadLocalMap - -Dio.netty.threadLocalMap.stringBuilder.initialSize: 1024
16:08:42.260 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.InternalThreadLocalMap - -Dio.netty.threadLocalMap.stringBuilder.maxSize: 4096
16:08:42.269 [main] DEBUG io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop - -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization: false
16:08:42.269 [main] DEBUG io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop - -Dio.netty.selectorAutoRebuildThreshold: 512
16:08:42.275 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent - org.jctools-core.MpscChunkedArrayQueue: available
16:08:42.456 [main] DEBUG io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelId - -Dio.netty.processId: 29622 (auto-detected)
16:08:42.461 [main] DEBUG io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelId - -Dio.netty.machineId: ac:de:48:ff:fe:00:11:22 (auto-detected)
16:08:42.484 [main] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.numHeapArenas: 16
16:08:42.484 [main] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.numDirectArenas: 16
16:08:42.484 [main] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.pageSize: 8192
16:08:42.484 [main] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.maxOrder: 9
16:08:42.484 [main] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.chunkSize: 4194304
16:08:42.484 [main] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.smallCacheSize: 256
16:08:42.484 [main] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.normalCacheSize: 64
16:08:42.484 [main] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.maxCachedBufferCapacity: 32768
16:08:42.484 [main] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.cacheTrimInterval: 8192
16:08:42.484 [main] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.cacheTrimIntervalMillis: 0
16:08:42.484 [main] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.useCacheForAllThreads: false
16:08:42.484 [main] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.maxCachedByteBuffersPerChunk: 1023
16:08:42.492 [main] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.ByteBufUtil - -Dio.netty.allocator.type: pooled
16:08:42.492 [main] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.ByteBufUtil - -Dio.netty.threadLocalDirectBufferSize: 0
16:08:42.492 [main] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.ByteBufUtil - -Dio.netty.maxThreadLocalCharBufferSize: 16384
16:08:42.516 [reactor-http-nio-1] DEBUG reactor.netty.resources.PooledConnectionProvider - [25420c6f] Created a new pooled channel, now: 0 active connections, 0 inactive connections and 0 pending acquire requests.
16:08:42.544 [reactor-http-nio-1] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf - -Dio.netty.buffer.checkAccessible: true
16:08:42.544 [reactor-http-nio-1] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf - -Dio.netty.buffer.checkBounds: true
16:08:42.545 [reactor-http-nio-1] DEBUG io.netty.util.ResourceLeakDetectorFactory - Loaded default ResourceLeakDetector: io.netty.util.ResourceLeakDetector@1e1ec0ea
16:08:42.551 [reactor-http-nio-1] DEBUG reactor.netty.transport.TransportConfig - [25420c6f] Initialized pipeline DefaultChannelPipeline{(HttpProxyHandler$HttpClientCodecWrapper#0 = io.netty.handler.proxy.HttpProxyHandler$HttpClientCodecWrapper), (reactor.left.proxyLoggingHandler = reactor.netty.transport.logging.ReactorNettyLoggingHandler), (reactor.left.proxyHandler = io.netty.handler.proxy.HttpProxyHandler), (reactor.left.loggingHandler = reactor.netty.transport.logging.ReactorNettyLoggingHandler), (reactor.left.httpCodec = io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpClientCodec), (reactor.right.reactiveBridge = reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler)}
16:08:42.552 [reactor-http-nio-1] DEBUG reactor.netty.proxy - [25420c6f] REGISTERED
16:08:42.552 [reactor-http-nio-1] DEBUG reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient - [25420c6f] REGISTERED
16:08:42.556 [reactor-http-nio-1] DEBUG reactor.netty.transport.TransportConnector - [25420c6f] Connecting to [xxxx:80].
16:08:42.556 [reactor-http-nio-1] DEBUG reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient - [25420c6f] CONNECT: xxxx:80
16:08:42.556 [reactor-http-nio-1] DEBUG reactor.netty.proxy - [25420c6f] CONNECT: xxxx:9504
16:08:42.676 [reactor-http-nio-1] DEBUG reactor.netty.resources.DefaultPooledConnectionProvider - [25420c6f, L:/x.x.x.x:62264 - R:xxxx:9504] Registering pool release on close event for channel
16:08:42.677 [reactor-http-nio-1] DEBUG reactor.netty.resources.PooledConnectionProvider - [25420c6f, L:/x.x.x.x:62264 - R:xxxx:9504] Channel connected, now: 1 active connections, 0 inactive connections and 0 pending acquire requests.
16:08:42.678 [reactor-http-nio-1] DEBUG reactor.netty.proxy - [25420c6f, L:/x.x.x.x:62264 - R:xxxx:9504] ACTIVE
16:08:42.687 [reactor-http-nio-1] DEBUG reactor.netty.proxy - [25420c6f, L:/x.x.x.x:62264 - R:xxxx:9504] WRITE, DefaultFullHttpRequest(decodeResult: success, version: HTTP/1.1, content: EmptyByteBufBE)
CONNECT xxxx:80 HTTP/1.1
host: xxxx:80, 0B
16:08:42.692 [reactor-http-nio-1] DEBUG io.netty.util.Recycler - -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread: 4096
16:08:42.693 [reactor-http-nio-1] DEBUG io.netty.util.Recycler - -Dio.netty.recycler.ratio: 8
16:08:42.693 [reactor-http-nio-1] DEBUG io.netty.util.Recycler - -Dio.netty.recycler.chunkSize: 32
16:08:42.693 [reactor-http-nio-1] DEBUG io.netty.util.Recycler - -Dio.netty.recycler.blocking: false
16:08:42.701 [reactor-http-nio-1] DEBUG reactor.netty.proxy - [25420c6f, L:/x.x.x.x:62264 - R:xxxx:9504] FLUSH
16:08:42.704 [reactor-http-nio-1] DEBUG reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient - [25420c6f, L:/x.x.x.x:62264 - R:xxxx:9504] ACTIVE
16:08:42.704 [reactor-http-nio-1] DEBUG reactor.netty.resources.DefaultPooledConnectionProvider - [25420c6f, L:/x.x.x.x:62264 - R:xxxx:9504] onStateChange(PooledConnection{channel=[id: 0x25420c6f, L:/x.x.x.x:62264 - R:xxxx:9504]}, [connected])
16:08:42.712 [reactor-http-nio-1] DEBUG reactor.netty.resources.DefaultPooledConnectionProvider - [25420c6f-1, L:/x.x.x.x:62264 - R:xxxx:9504] onStateChange(GET{uri=/, connection=PooledConnection{channel=[id: 0x25420c6f, L:/x.x.x.x:62264 - R:xxxx:9504]}}, [configured])
16:08:42.713 [reactor-http-nio-1] DEBUG reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect - [25420c6f-1, L:/x.x.x.x:62264 - R:xxxx:9504] Handler is being applied: {uri=http://xxxx/security/login.json, method=POST}
16:08:42.714 [reactor-http-nio-1] DEBUG reactor.netty.resources.DefaultPooledConnectionProvider - [25420c6f-1, L:/x.x.x.x:62264 - R:xxxx:9504] onStateChange(POST{uri=/security/login.json, connection=PooledConnection{channel=[id: 0x25420c6f, L:/x.x.x.x:62264 - R:xxxx:9504]}}, [request_prepared])
16:08:42.796 [reactor-http-nio-1] DEBUG org.springframework.http.codec.json.Jackson2JsonEncoder - [5ab956d7] Encoding [AuthBean(username=x, password=x)]
16:08:42.812 [reactor-http-nio-1] DEBUG reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient - [25420c6f-1, L:/x.x.x.x:62264 - R:xxxx:9504] WRITE: 254B
         +-------------------------------------------------+
         |  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
|00000000| 50 4f 53 54 20 2f 73 74 75 64 69 6f 2f 61 70 69 |POST /studio/api|
|00000010| 2f 31 2f 73 65 72 76 69 63 65 73 2f 61 70 69 2f |/1/services/api/|
|00000020| 31 2f 73 65 63 75 72 69 74 79 2f 6c 6f 67 69 6e |1/security/login|
|00000030| 2e 6a 73 6f 6e 20 48 54 54 50 2f 31 2e 31 0d 0a |.json HTTP/1.1..|
|00000040| 75 73 65 72 2d 61 67 65 6e 74 3a 20 52 65 61 63 |user-agent: Reac|
|00000050| 74 6f 72 4e 65 74 74 79 2f 31 2e 30 2e 31 37 0d |torNetty/1.0.17.|
|00000060| 0a 68 6f 73 74 3a 20 69 63 68 69 62 61 2d 63 6d |.host: xxxx.com..accept: |
|00000090| 2a 2f 2a 0d 0a 43 6f 6e 74 65 6e 74 2d 54 79 70 |*/*..Content-Typ|
|000000a0| 65 3a 20 61 70 70 6c 69 63 61 74 69 6f 6e 2f 6a |e: application/j|
|000000b0| 73 6f 6e 0d 0a 58 2d 58 53 52 46 2d 54 4f 4b 45 |son..X-XSRF-TOKE|
|000000c0| 4e 3a 20 41 5f 56 41 4c 55 45 0d 0a 63 6f 6f 6b |N: A_VALUE..cook|
|000000d0| 69 65 3a 20 58 53 52 46 2d 54 4f 4b 45 4e 3d 41 |ie: XSRF-TOKEN=A|
|000000e0| 5f 56 41 4c 55 45 0d 0a 63 6f 6e 74 65 6e 74 2d |_VALUE..content-|
|000000f0| 6c 65 6e 67 74 68 3a 20 35 37 0d 0a 0d 0a       |length: 57....  |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
16:08:42.814 [reactor-http-nio-1] DEBUG reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient - [25420c6f-1, L:/x.x.x.x:62264 - R:xxxx:9504] WRITE: 57B
         +-------------------------------------------------+
         |  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
|00000000| 7b 22 75 73 65 72 6e 61 6d 65 22 3a 22 65 6d 70 |{"username":"x","pass|
|00000020| 77 6f 72 64 22 3a 22 65 47 62 25 52 76 70 78 68 |word":"x"}       |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
16:08:42.814 [reactor-http-nio-1] DEBUG reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient - [25420c6f-1, L:/x.x.x.x:62264 - R:xxxx:9504] FLUSH
16:08:42.825 [reactor-http-nio-1] DEBUG reactor.netty.proxy - [25420c6f-1, L:/x.x.x.x:62264 - R:xxxx:9504] READ: DefaultHttpResponse(decodeResult: success, version: HTTP/1.0)
HTTP/1.0 200 Connection Established
Proxy-agent: Apache
16:08:42.825 [reactor-http-nio-1] DEBUG reactor.netty.proxy - [25420c6f-1, L:/x.x.x.x:62264 - R:xxxx:9504] READ, EmptyLastHttpContent, 0B
16:08:42.825 [reactor-http-nio-1] DEBUG reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient - [25420c6f-1, L:/x.x.x.x:62264 - R:xxxx:9504] USER_EVENT: ProxyConnectionEvent(http, none, xxxx:9504 => xxxx:80)
16:08:42.826 [reactor-http-nio-1] DEBUG reactor.netty.proxy - [25420c6f-1, L:/x.x.x.x:62264 - R:xxxx:9504] WRITE: 254B
         +-------------------------------------------------+
         |  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
|00000000| 50 4f 53 54 20 2f 73 74 75 64 69 6f 2f 61 70 69 |POST /studio/api|
|00000010| 2f 31 2f 73 65 72 76 69 63 65 73 2f 61 70 69 2f |/1/services/api/|
|00000020| 31 2f 73 65 63 75 72 69 74 79 2f 6c 6f 67 69 6e |1/security/login|
|00000030| 2e 6a 73 6f 6e 20 48 54 54 50 2f 31 2e 31 0d 0a |.json HTTP/1.1..|
|00000040| 75 73 65 72 2d 61 67 65 6e 74 3a 20 52 65 61 63 |user-agent: Reac|
|00000050| 74 6f 72 4e 65 74 74 79 2f 31 2e 30 2e 31 37 0d |torNetty/1.0.17.|
|00000060| 0a 68 6f 73 74 3a 20 69 63 68 69 62 61 2d 63 6d |.host: xxxx.com..accept: |
|00000090| 2a 2f 2a 0d 0a 43 6f 6e 74 65 6e 74 2d 54 79 70 |*/*..Content-Typ|
|000000a0| 65 3a 20 61 70 70 6c 69 63 61 74 69 6f 6e 2f 6a |e: application/j|
|000000b0| 73 6f 6e 0d 0a 58 2d 58 53 52 46 2d 54 4f 4b 45 |son..X-XSRF-TOKE|
|000000c0| 4e 3a 20 41 5f 56 41 4c 55 45 0d 0a 63 6f 6f 6b |N: A_VALUE..cook|
|000000d0| 69 65 3a 20 58 53 52 46 2d 54 4f 4b 45 4e 3d 41 |ie: XSRF-TOKEN=A|
|000000e0| 5f 56 41 4c 55 45 0d 0a 63 6f 6e 74 65 6e 74 2d |_VALUE..content-|
|000000f0| 6c 65 6e 67 74 68 3a 20 35 37 0d 0a 0d 0a       |length: 57....  |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
16:08:42.826 [reactor-http-nio-1] DEBUG reactor.netty.proxy - [25420c6f-1, L:/x.x.x.x:62264 - R:xxxx:9504] WRITE: 57B
         +-------------------------------------------------+
         |  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
|00000000| 7b 22 75 73 65 72 6e 61 6d 65 22 3a 22 65 6d 70 |{"username":"x","pass|
|00000020| 77 6f 72 64 22 3a 22 65 47 62 25 52 76 70 78 68 |word":"x"}       |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
16:08:42.826 [reactor-http-nio-1] DEBUG reactor.netty.proxy - [25420c6f-1, L:/x.x.x.x:62264 - R:xxxx:9504] FLUSH
16:08:42.827 [reactor-http-nio-1] DEBUG reactor.netty.resources.DefaultPooledConnectionProvider - [25420c6f-1, L:/x.x.x.x:62264 - R:xxxx:9504] onStateChange(POST{uri=/studio/api/1/services/api/1/security/login.json, connection=PooledConnection{channel=[id: 0x25420c6f, L:/x.x.x.x:62264 - R:xxxx:9504]}}, [request_sent])
16:08:42.828 [reactor-http-nio-1] DEBUG reactor.netty.proxy - [25420c6f-1, L:/x.x.x.x:62264 - R:xxxx:9504] READ COMPLETE
16:08:42.977 [reactor-http-nio-1] DEBUG reactor.netty.proxy - [25420c6f-1, L:/x.x.x.x:62264 - R:xxxx:9504] READ: 552B


16:08:42.980 [reactor-http-nio-1] DEBUG reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientOperations - [25420c6f-1, L:/x.x.x.x:62264 - R:xxxx:9504] Received response (auto-read:false) : [Date=Thu, 12 May 2022 07:08:42 GMT, Server=Apache, Vary=Origin,Accept-Encoding,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers, Cache-Control=no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate, Pragma=no-cache, Expires=0, X-XSS-Protection=1; mode=block, X-Frame-Options=SAMEORIGIN, Content-Type=application/json;charset=UTF-8, Content-Language=en-US, Set-Cookie=JSESSIONID=B483A877C263DF2C9F9CEC520E911246; Path=/studio; HttpOnly, Connection=close, Transfer-Encoding=chunked]
16:08:42.980 [reactor-http-nio-1] DEBUG reactor.netty.resources.DefaultPooledConnectionProvider - [25420c6f-1, L:/x.x.x.x:62264 - R:xxxx:9504] onStateChange(POST{uri=/studio/api/1/services/api/1/security/login.json, connection=PooledConnection{channel=[id: 0x25420c6f, L:/x.x.x.x:62264 - R:xxxx:9504]}}, [response_received])
16:08:42.984 [reactor-http-nio-1] DEBUG org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunctions - [5ab956d7] [25420c6f-1, L:/x.x.x.x:62264 - R:xxxx:9504] Response 401 UNAUTHORIZED
16:08:43.018 [reactor-http-nio-1] DEBUG reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive - [25420c6f-1, L:/x.x.x.x:62264 - R:xxxx:9504] FluxReceive{pending=0, cancelled=false, inboundDone=false, inboundError=null}: subscribing inbound receiver
16:08:43.021 [reactor-http-nio-1] DEBUG reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientOperations - [25420c6f-1, L:/x.x.x.x:62264 - R:xxxx:9504] Received last HTTP packet
16:08:43.022 [reactor-http-nio-1] DEBUG org.springframework.core.codec.ByteArrayDecoder - [5ab956d7] [25420c6f-1, L:/x.x.x.x:62264 - R:xxxx:9504] Read 26 bytes
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException$Unauthorized: 401 Unauthorized from POST http://xxxx/security/login.json
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException.create(WebClientResponseException.java:198)
    Suppressed: The stacktrace has been enhanced by Reactor, refer to additional information below: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    *__checkpoint ⇢ 401 from POST http://xxxx/security/login.json [DefaultWebClient]
Original Stack Trace:
        at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException.create(WebClientResponseException.java:198)
        at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultClientResponse.lambda$createException$1(DefaultClientResponse.java:207)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:106)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:79)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefaultIfEmpty$DefaultIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxDefaultIfEmpty.java:101)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:127)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWrite$ContextWriteSubscriber.onNext(FluxContextWrite.java:107)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:295)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilterFuseable.java:337)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1816)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCollect$CollectSubscriber.onComplete(MonoCollect.java:159)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:142)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onComplete(FluxPeek.java:260)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:142)
        at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.onInboundComplete(FluxReceive.java:400)
        at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onInboundComplete(ChannelOperations.java:419)
        at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.terminate(ChannelOperations.java:473)
        at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientOperations.onInboundNext(HttpClientOperations.java:703)
        at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:93)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:327)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:299)
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
        at io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler.channelRead(LoggingHandler.java:280)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
        at io.netty.handler.proxy.ProxyHandler.channelRead(ProxyHandler.java:252)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
        at io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler.channelRead(LoggingHandler.java:280)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436)
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:253)
        at io.netty.handler.proxy.HttpProxyHandler$HttpClientCodecWrapper.channelRead(HttpProxyHandler.java:272)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:722)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:658)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:584)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:496)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986)
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Suppressed: java.lang.Exception: #block terminated with an error
        at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:99)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1707)
        at jp.co.xx.yy.sample.togglz.fm.client.Test.main(Test.java:38)
16:08:43.038 [reactor-http-nio-1] DEBUG reactor.netty.resources.DefaultPooledConnectionProvider - [25420c6f, L:/x.x.x.x:62264 - R:xxxx:9504] onStateChange(POST{uri=/studio/api/1/services/api/1/security/login.json, connection=PooledConnection{channel=[id: 0x25420c6f, L:/x.x.x.x:62264 - R:xxxx:9504]}}, [response_completed])
16:08:43.038 [reactor-http-nio-1] DEBUG reactor.netty.resources.DefaultPooledConnectionProvider - [25420c6f, L:/x.x.x.x:62264 - R:xxxx:9504] onStateChange(POST{uri=/studio/api/1/services/api/1/security/login.json, connection=PooledConnection{channel=[id: 0x25420c6f, L:/x.x.x.x:62264 - R:xxxx:9504]}}, [disconnecting])
16:08:43.038 [reactor-http-nio-1] DEBUG reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient - [25420c6f, L:/x.x.x.x:62264 - R:xxxx:9504] CLOSE
16:08:43.038 [reactor-http-nio-1] DEBUG reactor.netty.proxy - [25420c6f, L:/x.x.x.x:62264 - R:xxxx:9504] CLOSE

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Did you got any solution. We are facing the same issue?